# Distinguishing Between Retrieval Augmented Generation and Large Language Models for Dialogue Applications

Tags: large-language-model

I am working on a dialogue application using a Retrieval-Augmented Generation (RAG) approach with a Large Language Model. The system retrieves responses from a database based on the input question. However, there are cases where the similarity between the retrieved data and the original question is low.

I am looking for guidance on how to effectively distinguish between using the retrieved data and relying on the model's inherent generation capabilities when faced with low similarity. Are there specific strategies or best practices for making this decision?

Here are some specific points I am interested in:

```
1. How can I set an appropriate similarity threshold to decide when to use the retrieved data and when to rely on the model's generation capabilities?

2. Are there methods for evaluating the confidence or certainty of the model's generated answers, and how can this be used to inform the decision-making process?
```

I would appreciate any insights, theories, or practical advice on optimizing the use of retrieved data and the model's generation capabilities in a dialogue application using RAG. Thank you!